# How could I implement multiple dimensional arrays like this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, matlab

I'm porting MATLAB code to Javascript, and I came across some code that looks like this:

```
MatrixVar(a, b, c, c, i) = y_var(i);
```

How could I go about implementing something like `MatrixVar` in Javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that exact syntax (with parens), `MatrixVar` would have to be a function in JavaScript. But it can't be a function, because you would be assigning to whatever the function returns.

Multi-dimensional arrays look like `arr[a][b][c][c][i]`, and are in fact nested arrays:

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    // create new nested arrays
    arr[i] = [];
    for(var j=0; j<3; j++) {
        // populate nested arrays
        arr[i][j] = j;
    }
}
```

At the end, `arr` will look like this:

```
[
    [0,1,2],
    [0,1,2],
    [0,1,2]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make little helper to access your multidimensional array indexes with a function, something like this:

Given:

```
var arr = [[[[['foo']]]]];
```

An this helper:

```
Array.prototype.access = function(){
  var last = this;
  for (var a=0; a<arguments.length; a++){
    last = last[arguments[a]];
  }
  return last;
};
```

If you want to print "foo", instead of `arr[0][0][0][0][0]` you can do:

```
arr.access(0,0,0,0,0); //=> "foo"
```

Comment: However, to replace `'foo'` with something else you'd have to use `arr.access(0,0,0,0)[0] = 'bar'`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a library. Seriously. I can't vouch for it, but this one looks nice and supports n-dimensional arrays: [mathjs](https://npmjs.org/package/mathjs). Also see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306325/javascript-numerical-library-vectors-matrices-determinates-inversion).